# Which design pattern for my proxy Rule

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

I have a proxy HttpHandler that gets a url from user as a querystring parameter like following.

```
public class MagicProxy : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
       string requestUrl = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(context.Request.QueryString["url"]);
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

url parameter is like this:

```
http://server1.com/service?method=get&request=GetInfo
http://server1.com/service?method=get&request=GetFeatures
http://server1.com/service?method=get&request=GetImage&Format=PNG
```

I am parsing url querystring. Because some users can use **`method=get`** and can not use `method=post`. Some users can use 
`request=GetInfo` and some users can not use reguest=GetImage.

These are my rules by users. I want to use desgin pattern to implement these rules. But I could not decide to use.
Specification, Strategy, or else. I am new at desing patterns.

```
public interface IRule{}
public class UserCanUseGetMethod:IRule{}
```

How can I combine rules and user?

Answer (score 1):

[*Specification*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specification_pattern) should be a good bet:

```
if(someSpec.IsSatisfiedBy(request)) 
{

}
```

Where `request` can be either the HTTP request *as is* or an arbitrary class that you may design as a value object with the desired properties.

It seems like your interface could look like this:

```
public interface ISpecification<T>
{
    bool IsSatisfiedBy(T some);
}
```

This will allow you to use this pattern everywhere, and since it supports a `T` generic type parameter to provide the type of objects to specify, it seems like you'll be able to re-use in other situations where you'll need specifications!